# ASP.NET: Why does it take forever to load a page after compiling?

Tags: asp.net

Why does it take forever for ASP.NET to process a request the first time you try to access the site after compiling?

Maybe it's just me but the first time I visit a page after I've compiled my project, it takes about 20 seconds before I receive a response. Why is this?

Comment: Your question is far to general.  Can you please give us some specifics.

Comment: Actually its not - this is a generic problem with ASP.NET

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the pages are not completely "compiled" until you run them for the first time.

See the following page regarding [Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The first load is slow because the just-in-time-compiler is kicking in. If you are using the Web Application model you are only compiling the code behind files. The markup files still need to compiled before they can be shown, and this is done in real time. If you are using the Web Site model both markup and code behind files a compiled just-in-time.

[Microsoft's ASP.NET Compilation Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863.aspx) can be used to pre-compile the whole web site, so that you can eliminate the first delay.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what changes you've made.
If you've changed a single page then that is the only page that needs recompiling.
If you've changed/added code in app_code then the whole application needs to be recompiled.